# Is there any way to get the Firefox API's

Tags: firefox, firefox-3, firefox3.5

Is there any way to get firefox Api so that i can access them programatially

There any other method other than XPCom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

(Well, maybe [this](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm), but it's out of date.)